# When to delete objects from the heap in C++?

Tags: c++

I am a little confused when/how to delete objects from the heap in C++.

When:

If you are executing a program which is relatively short, computes something and then passes standard output to the console is it worth destroying all your objects just after the console has output the result or would the program destroy automatically upon exiting? In the case of large programs I presume it would definitely be better practice to try and work out when you no longer need any of your objects?

How:

If I have a vector containing pointers to MyClass objects, once I am finished with the vector (and MyClass objects) how do I write a destructor that can destroy all the MyClass objects pointed to by the vector? (Obviously I will need to destroy the vector too).

Comment: For your `How`, you shouldn't need to destroy the vector itself if the vector itself is on the stack. To delete every pointer inside, iterate through and call delete on each element. You should rather opt for smart pointers instead though.

Comment: If the program does some computation for a short duration and then exits, I don't think you need to worry about freeing up the objects as every resource held by the program is freed as soon as the program quits.

Comment: While people will tell you that it's ok to leak for short programs get into the habit of allocing and deleting. It's good practice

Comment: “It’s a question of style … **Sloppy work tends to be habit-forming**.” – Silk in *Castle of Wizardry* by David Eddings.

Comment: I just want to echo larsman's comment above.  If you're programming in such a way that you need to explicitly call delete (or delete[]) in order to free memory, you're subjecting yourself to large quantities of unnecessary suffering.  The time you invest in learning about smart pointers (and in particular shared_ptr) and RAII programming style is an investment that will pay off many times over in the form of time saved by not having to track down memory leaks and/or crashes due to prematurely freed objects.  Make a habit of using smart pointers, you won't be sorry.

Answer (score 5):

It’s a very simple contract – one of the simplest in all of programming: **if you allocate a resource you promise to the API that you will free it appropriately.**

Not doing so *will* have averse consequences. From waste of heap space to [nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html) chewing on your entrails.

The fact is that there simply is no excuse not to free resources you have requested. Not doing so is sloppy, and I would see it as indicative of generally bad code quality (because it *is*!).

Furthermore, C++ makes incredibly easy not to have to make this decision: simply don’t produce garbage, then you don’t need to clean up. Don’t allocate freestore memory, or if you absolutely have to, use smart pointers or special allocators to manage it.

If you use C++ properly, there simply is no compelling technical reason to be sloppy with resources, and plenty of incentive to pay attention.

As for the “how”, I’d question the decision to store pointers in the first place: raw C++ pointers shouldn’t own memory. If you really need freestore memory, use smart pointers, or (preferably) use automatic objects instead: since they are in a vector, this already gives you the ownership and storage location and the vector class takes care of that memory automatically.

If you need polymorphic objects, you unfortunately *need* to store pointers. In that case, there are several possibilities but the simplest is probably the usage of smart pointers.

Comment: Of course the last paragraph only applies to actual run-time polymorphism. Which in many languages is the only kind of polymorphism, but in C++ it can often be pushed to compile-time via templates, and then there is no need to explicitly store pointers.

Comment: Konrad is right. I was unclear in my answer: the first thing to learn is to manage your resources properly. If (and only if) you have a specific case where a forced exit gives you a significant advantage over cleaning up properly, and you have the numbers to prove it, then you may be forgiven for your sins!

Comment: @Konrad " I’d question the decision to store pointers in the first place" could you please elaborate on this?

Comment: @user997112 Like I said, raw pointers should never own memory, there are better tools for that. In general, [don’t use pointers](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6101039/Modern%20C%2B%2B.pdf).

Comment: @leftaroundabout You are of course right but the term “polymorphic object” (as opposed to just “polymorphism”) is typically exclusively used for objects with virtual methods.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't destroy objects when you're done with them, you are heading towards a memory/resource leak. If you lose track of the objects, then you have a leak.

This is a problem in a long running program, because you can run out of memory or resources. It's a bad sign in any program if objects are not properly kept track of. You made the object, why can't you destroy it too?

Most (every?) operating system will reclaim allocated memory from a process when the process exits, so you do not need to tidy up after yourself. In some cases avoiding this pointless tidying up may mean your users aren't waiting for too long when your process completes.

If your program behaves like this, it makes your code less available for re-use. If you want to package it into a library, you'll have to deal with this problem because you cannot know ahead of time how your library will be used.

As for your vector of pointers: iterate the vector and call delete on each pointer. Then destroy the vector.

Answer (score 1):

> how do I write a destructor that can destroy all the MyClass objects pointed to by the vector?

Very good question! A class with such a destructor is called a *smart pointer*, and they are supplied by libraries like Boost, TR1, and the C++11 standard library, at least one of which probably came with your platform.

You should almost never use `new T` directly. Use [`unique_ptr<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) for straightforward ownership (the object persists if and only if the vector still exists) or [`shared_ptr<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) for shared ownership.  These templates exist in namespace `boost::`, `std::tr1::`, or `std::` depending on how you obtain them. The interfaces are much the same in any case.

Of course, you shouldn't use any kind of pointer at all if you can avoid it. `vector<T>` is preferable over `vector< unique_ptr< T > >` any day.

As for *whether* to free resources before exiting, of course you should. Good C++ practices make it harder to neglect to release resources than to do things correctly, so it's not really something we worry about.

Comment: I am not using C++11, would it be good enough to use auto_ptr?

Comment: You can still use boost. Much better than `auto_ptr`.

Comment: @user997112 `auto_ptr` cannot be stored inside a container, so it doesn't solve this problem and it's been deprecated. You almost certainly already have TR1 available, or if you prefer use Boost.

Answer (score -3):

For short-running programs it's OK to not delete the objects.    There is no adverse consequence.

But well-designed application code is re-usable, and re-usable code is basically library code.   Library code should delete the objects it allocates, because it might be used in a long-running program.

So in other words, don't worry about it for a throw-away small program.    But for serious code, delete the objects rather than leaking them.

Comment: It's still a good thing to practice. Some things like those found in the Windows API can exist past the end of the program. I think vertex buffers are one of those things, but I could be remembering wrong. Something in DirectX jumps to mind.

Comment: –1, and if I could I would downvote more: this is sloppy programming. It’s bad advice. Don’t do it – not even for short programs … in particular since there’s no advantage to this. Just don’t produce garbage if you’re allergic to clean-up.

Comment: In fairness, there *can* be advantages to it, but not in small programs. Large, complex programs may take significant time to shut down, because of all the destructors that need to run. In those cases, bypassing them and just leaking memory (which the OS reclaims anyway) may be preferable. However, that is a very different situation than what is suggested here (which is basically "don't bother learning/getting into the habit of managing your memory correctly"). You *should* handle memory and other resources correctly by default. In exceptional cases, you might choose to deviate from this

Comment: @chris: There is the global COM heap, as far as I am aware, which is indeed process-independent and the OS cannot reclaim memory allocated from it. But that's my vague memory.

Comment: @jalf A more elegant way to perform that optimization would be to override `::operator delete` to no-op if a global flag is set indicating app shutdown.